# Deep discharge protection of LiFePo4 cell with a single MOSFET with the right threshold voltage

Tags: batteries, protection

Is it possible to build a deep-discharge protection circuit for lithium based rechargeable batteries by putting a simple enhancement mode MOSFET with a threshold voltage that is equal to the discharge voltage (e.g. 2.5 volts for LiFePo4 cells) in line with the load? The circuit need not carry more than 1A I guess.

A first simulation (with the first reasonably suitable MOSFET I have found in the library) in LTSPICE seems to work. R1 is the load. If that is so easy, why doesn't everybody do it that way? Am I missing something?

[image]

**To the background of my question**: because I have long been sick of constantly juggling throw-away alkaline batteries for my WiiMote controllers, I have ordered myself 14500-type LiFePo4 batteries (Nickel based rechargeables are not an option because they have lower average voltage 1.2 V, which the WiiMote doesn't seem to like). Since they have a nominal voltage of 3.2 volts, one such cell is able to replace two alkaline batteries at 1.5 volts (I assume the WiiMote has a margin of safety for overvoltage). And it supplies more constant voltage than the alkalines, allowing to use more of the capacity until the WiiMotes refuse to work.

But then I have to protect the LiFePo4's against deep discharging below 2.5 volts. There are some small BMS boards from China, but they are more expensive than the batteries themselves and take a month to deliver (and maybe a few years more in times of Chinese Corona). Moreover, I don't need protection against overcharging or overcurrent, let alone cell balancing. Just plain and simple deep discharge protection. I know there are dedicated IC's for that out there, but I would prefer a true minimalist solution.

Comment: Can you build the schematic you mention in your first paragraph so we can get a better idea of how you imagine the circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several points to take into account (some of them seem quite near a red flag for a commercial application, but it might be OK for a one time project).

Lets look at the datasheet of the [Si7336ADP](https://www.vishay.com/docs/73152/si7336adp.pdf) you use in your simulation :

- p2 : Gate Threshold Voltage (Tj=25°C, VDS = VGS , ID = 250 μA) : min=1V, max=3V : the threshold voltage is very badly defined (even when fixing 3 parameters) : if it happens to be 1.0V, you destroy your mosfet. If it happens to be 3.0V, you loose a lot of capacity of your battery. NB : it is not specified on what this value depends: it might be part-to-part variability (then you can test your part and use it if you are happy with it), or it can be changing with some parameters (aging, magnetic field, or whatever else) in which case, you might test it succesfully one day, and it might have a totally different value the next day.
- p2 : figure "Transfer Characteristics" : as you see, there is no "strong" trheshold : so you have a whole range of voltages where you will still drain some current, but probably no longer enough to power properly your device
- p4, figure "Threshold Voltage": as you can see, you can get some change in threshold voltage due to temperature change : nb : it is junction temperature, so it might rise far above room temperature, specially near the voltage threshold, where the "resistance" of the mosfet increases a lot
- current leakage : I haven't found parameters really relevant for your situation (maybe because that mosfet is intended for digital use), but it might also be an issue.

So, with the mosfet you used for your simulation, the datasheet does NOT garantee that it will work properly. It might, or it might not. For commercial applications, this is a no-go (it might work on one production batch, and fail on the next one, or after aging, ...).

For a hobby application, you might give it a try if you wish, knowing that it might work or not. And accepting the fact that it migt stop to work/fail randomly (NB : this includes making sure to recharge your battery with a charger that won't charge it if in deep discharge, otherwise it might catch fire if you damaged it by deep discharge)

Comment: Thanks, very good points. It is surprising that the specification is so weak on this. Especially the aging or random influence issue would be prohibitive. Probably the current leakage issue is the most irrelevant, because for a switching application one often relies on low silent current.  Maybe I will try to find datasheets that are more verbose about these topics. I remembered, just after writing my question, that I have some IRLR3110 (logic level) in my parts tray. I think I will do some tests after I have dug through the stuff in the attic. So that doesn't cost me money - it's just a DIY.

Comment: BTW, could there be a way to "sharpen" the threshold voltage, e.g. with a Z-Diode? I have no experience with using Z-diodes, but I feel there must be something.

Comment: For why specification is "weak" : simply because the Si7336ADP is designed for DC-DC converters, which use "big" voltages on the gate, so the exact threshold voltage doesn't matter. And the more precisely you want to specify, the more expensive the production and testing are. Why to increase price to improve the specification of a parameter "nobody" cares about?

Comment: For leakage current : the Si7336ADP is for DC/DC converters, and is rated up to 30A. So even if it is only 5A in average, you don't care if you have 50mA (1%) leaking. For your application, 50mA is a huge problem. Still, I expect to be only a few µA when Vgs=0V. However, in your situation, you have Vgs just bellow threshold voltage, so I would expect a rather "big" leakage : the "leakage" current is continuous : so at Vgs-1mV, you will have nearly the same current as at Vgs+1mV. So you will not go from 300mA to 0mA at once, but descrease slowly, with voltage going down (until which, no idea)

Comment: IRLR3110 : I don't expect it to work : Vgs is 1.0 to 2.5V, so it will probably cut off far bellow 2.5V (maybe you can use a voltage dividor with HUGE resistors to avoid too much leakage). For the Zener diodes, I can't see right now how it might help (they are usefull to remove voltage above some voltage, but not to make a voltage go to 0)